# Is 999...9 a real number in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
sub is_integer {
   defined $_[0] && $_[0] =~ /^[+-]?\d+$/;
}

sub is_float {
   defined $_[0] && $_[0] =~ /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
}
```

For the code mentioned above, if we give input as `999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`, it is giving output as not real number.

Why it is behaving like that?

I forgot to mention one more thing:

If I am using this code for `$x` as the above value:

```
if($x > 0 || $x <= 0 ) {
print "Real";
}
```

Output is `real`.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

```
$ perl -e 'print 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'
1e+42
```

i.e. Perl uses scientific representation for this number and that is why your regexp doesn't match.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `looks_like_number` function from [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) (which is a core module).

```
use Scalar::Util qw( looks_like_number );

say "Number" if looks_like_number 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;

# above prints "Number"
```

Comment: Scalar::Util is a core module so it comes with Perl

Comment: Meaning the 'use' command above will work without installing anything.  However, if it objects to 'say', use 'print' instead ('say' is a bit modern and doesn't work in Perl 5.8).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add one more thing. As others have explained, the number you are working with is out of range for a Perl integer (unless you are on a 140 bit machine). Therefore, the variable will be stored as a floating point number. Regular expressions operate on strings. Therefore, the number is converted to its string representation before the regular expression operates on it.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained what is going on: out of the box, Perl can't handle numbers that large without using scientific notation.

If you need to work with large numbers, take a look at [bignum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) or its components, such as [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Math-BigInt-1.89/lib/Math/BigInt.pm). For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;

my $big_str = '900000000000000000000000000000000000000';
my $big_num = Math::BigInt->new($big_str);

$big_num ++;
print "Is integer: $big_num\n" if is_integer($big_num);

sub is_integer {
   defined $_[0] && $_[0] =~ /^[+-]?\d+$/;
}
```

Comment: Re "*Perl can't handle numbers that large without using scientific notation.*", Poppycock. Perl has no problems with `999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`, and Perl can also emit numbers that large without using scientific notation (e.g. using `sprintf %f` instead of stringification)

Comment: @ikegami The phrasing might be off (and feel free to suggest edits if your motives are constructive), but "poppycock" seems a bit overboard. For example, run this: `perl -we '$n = 99999999999999999999; $n ++'` You'll see: `Lost precision when incrementing ...`. At a minimum, one needs to make special arrangements in Perl to work with large integers -- unlike some other languages (eg Python).

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with the fact that stringification uses scientific notation for large numbers

Comment: @ikegami Consider why Perl's default behavior is to stringify very large integers using scientific notation. Part of the reason is surely to convey that the number is being handled, under the hood, with less precision than a user might expect. Stringification relates to the underlying implementation in sensible ways. To say that one has absolutely nothing to do with the other seems overly narrow.

Comment: You might have a point except that It uses scientific notation for numbers it can represent perfectly. The reason scientific notation is used for stringification, just like the reason it decimal positions are truncated when scientific notation isn't used, is to keep the stringification to a reasonable length

Answer (score 1):

Also, you may want to take a look at [bignum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) in the Perl documentation.